# Facebook Graph API privacy setting CUSTOM with allow return error - (#100) Only friends may be specified in allow and deny lists

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I am trying to do the following in Facebook Graph Explorer using my **app's token**.

```
POST /v2.6/me/live_videos?description=hello%20world&privacy={'value':'CUSTOM','allow':'<friend id>'}&title=welcome
```

But I am getting the following error, am I doing anything wrong? Should the **friend id** be app-scoped user id instead?

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Only friends may be specified in allow and deny lists",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "BOcQttKPs5W"
  }
}`

Comment: You trying to post a live video on your app?

Comment: no, to post a live video on my facebook page using my app (test)

Comment: You are posting to /me/live_videos

Comment: what is supposed to be there then? basically I wanted to post it to my page but only allow few friends to see it

Comment: _“Should the friend id be app-scoped user id instead?”_ – try it and find out …?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you need to know so-called "app scoped user id" of the friend you want to add.